# API Manager: Error when call a BPS subscription task

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-business-process

Im trying to follow this tutorial:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+an+API+Subscription+Workflow
But when I try to register a subscription from the Store, in BPS console I receive the following error:

```
[2016-06-28 11:21:10,729]  WARN    {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.b4p.extension.PeopleActivity} -  SOAP Fault: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action><wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:fd3c1de4-2689-4743-bfad-a31de7d726af</wsa:RelatesTo></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring><detail/></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

In BPS logs I have also this error but I can't find information about how the Nullpointer is generated:

```
[2016-06-28 11:21:10,767]  WARN {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess} -  Instance 1101 of {http://workflow.subscription.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org}SubscriptionApprovalWorkFlowProcess-2 has completed with fault: FaultData: [faultName={http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/bpel4people/bpel4people/200803}nonRecoverableError, faulType=null ({http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/bpel4people/bpel4people/200803}nonRecoverableError: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action><wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:fd3c1de4-2689-4743-bfad-a31de7d726af</wsa:RelatesTo></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring><detail/></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>)] @108 {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess}
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the scenario you have mentioned based on the document shared by you. However, I was able to get the flow to work as expected. On my end the API-Manager version was 1.10.0 and BPS was 3.2.0.

Could you verify the steps again as given on the document. If the default user name and password is not used the document guides on what places we may need to change.

Appreciate if you can provide answers for the following
Is the API manager setup on your end  a stand-a-lone or a cluster setup

Further appreciate if you can provide the version of the business process server that you have used as well as the jdk version.

regards,shavantha